# como trocar a virgula por ponto ao importar um arquivo xml de uma nota fiscal:

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, este é um resumo do meu código PY, estou com  dificuldade em tratar a troca de ponto por virgula antes de importar o resultado para uma planilha excel.
Estou estou usando o seguinte codigo para tratar: `df = valores ({',': '.'}, regex=True)`
Por favor alguem consegue me ajudar? preciso que o valor_Nf venha com virgula ex: 255,26 no arquivo xml está 255.26

```
def pegar_infos(nome_arquivo, valores):
    with open(f'cat6/{nome_arquivo}', "rb") as arquivo_xml:
         dic_arquivo = xmltodict.parse(arquivo_xml)

         if "NFe" in dic_arquivo:
             infos_nf = dic_arquivo["NFe"]['infNFe']
         else:
             infos_nf = dic_arquivo['nfeProc']["NFe"]['infNFe']

         valor_Nf = infos_nf["total"]["ICMSTot"]["vNF"]
        
         valores.append([valor_Nf])
lista_arquivos = os.listdir("cat6")
colunas = ["valor_Nf"]
valores = []
for arquivo in lista_arquivos:
pegar_infos(arquivo, valores)


tabela = pd.DataFrame(columns=colunas, data=valores)
tabela.to_excel("NotasFiscais.xlsx", index=False)

df = valores ({',': '.'}, regex=True)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Melhore o título e adicione um amostra de dados de poucas linhas para testar o código(pode ser um stub simulando a leitura de dados da planilha).

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.